# PHP - Read json from the file starting from the end

Tags: php

I have got a variable **$file**, where i store json :

```
[{"text":"Sample text 1","time":"Monday 18th of September 2017 05:54:07 PM"},{"text":"Sample text 2","time":"Monday 18th of September 2017 05:54:12 PM"}]
```

Everything works fine, i am using

> $data = file_get_contents( $file );

to read those data from the file. But i want to read it from the newest, thus from the end. Is it possible ?

Comment: sure, just use **array_reverse()** after `json_decode()`ing it. http://php.net/array_reverse

Comment: thank u very much ! but do i need ajax to make it work ?

Comment: Nope, it's a php function, everything in your question and this tip is server-side. You might need ajax afterwards but that's another topic